# Django admin page dropdowns

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, admin

I am building a high school team application using Django.

Here is my working models file:

```
class Directory(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    website = models.URLField()
    district = models.SmallIntegerField()
    conference = models.ForeignKey(Conference)
class Conference(models.Model):
    conference_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['conference_name']
```

When I open my admin pages and go to edit a school's conference the drop down looks like this:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Conference Object</option>
<option value="2">Conference Object</option>
<select>
```

How do I replace "Conference Object" with the conference_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Conference(models.Model):
    conference_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.conference_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['conference_name']
```

This will say to the framework how to convert `Conference` instances to unicode strings.

Comment: hey thanks so much. as I am getting off the ground here with the framework, thank you for being patient. I know I will use this again.